# When I try to convert a list of characters to a list of integers, the values change. How do I fix this?

Tags: list, kotlin, type-conversion

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val list = arrayListOf<Char>()
    val string: String = "731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491"
        loop@ for (char in string) {
            list.add(char)
            if (list.size == 13) {
                break@loop
            }
        }
    val trueList = list.map { it.toInt() }
    println(list)
    println(trueList)
}
```

Whenever I try to print this out, the values change. Instead of printing out "7,3,1, etc.," it prints out "55,51,59, etc."

Here is a snippet of what I'm talking about. I've first printed the list of characters, and then the list of integers.

```
[7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3] // List of the characters
[55, 51, 49, 54, 55, 49, 55, 54, 53, 51, 49, 51, 51] // List of integers
```

Comment: That is the character code points of those digits. You need to cast to an integer to get their numerical representation, or parse them, depending on how java does this.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen `char` is a [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-1) _code unit,_ not a [Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) _codepoint._ The difference would show up with codepoints that UTF-16 needs two code units for. Examples:    

Comment: 55 is the code point for the digit 7 though, same with all the others. I know full and well that char != code point but in this case, 55 is for 7, 51 for 3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is printing out the ascii value of each individual character instead of the string representation.

See https://ascii.cl/

```
var list = string.chunked(1).map { it.toInt() }
```

Comment: So could I just subtract 48 from each integer to get the proper value?

Comment: easier to use String.toInt like above